# CakePHP model association like "Facebook Likes"

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook-like, models, model-associations

I try to do something that is best described like Facebooks "Like"  with CakePHP.
I have four tables: Users, Likes, Posts and Pictures. A user can like an post or an picture and I try to have only one type of likes for both possibilities.

I also want to use as little code in the Controller as possible.

Is there a "native" CakePHP way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the [CakeDC "Favorites" plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/favorites).

Other than that, there is no built-in way to "like" something in CakePHP.  But using CakePHP to do that makes it pretty simple.

(This isn't the place for people to just post "how-to" code.  If you post what you've tried, or what your thoughts are so far, we can certainly help out and point you in the right direction or where you're doing things wrong...etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Cake PHP will natively make views for tables that are designed in the way they expect.  In this case you should probably have 2 "Likes" tables since your foreign key will link to different tables.

For example: 
Likes_Posts : user_id, post_id
Likes_Pictures : user_id, picture_id

This way you can make a users view that will show all of their likes.  CakePHP would be able to do this "auto-magically" with the Bake.  If you try to use one field foreign key to 2 different tables, you will confuse CakePHP (and maybe yourself!).  Hope this helps...

Comment: Not a good idea to store identical data (likes) in multiple tables.  Better to use foreign_key, model in a single "likes" table.